# Windows 10 Driver(without hardware device) with Error 39, 0xc0000603, Certificate Revoked

Tags: drivers, certificate, digital-signature, code-signing

Well, the driver was signed by EV Signing Certificate and Microsoft Windows Hardware Compatibility Publisher(WHLK\WHQL)

[image: Signatures]

[image: Signed by Microsfot]

With Secure Boot on Win 10 machine, I got the error code 39(Windows cannot verify the digital signature for this file. The signing certificate for this file has been revoked.)

Here is the full [setup log](https://gist.github.com/7934345/9e9402f739b17f8773b80bc2f9e6c8b7#file-log-L151).

The EV Signing Certificate's SN is not in its CRL Distribution Point list.

[image: CRL]

So, why dose device manager told me my driver's certificate for this file has been revoked?

BTW on Windows 10 and later, its recommend using [HLK](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/hlk/getstarted/windows-hlk-getting-started) not HCK.

[image: The ZH-CN Translation leads the misunderstanding], thx for the help of @user71659. Now everything works well.

Comment: Why are you censoring the name of the driver? If we know the name of the driver, we could find out what's going on behind it. Likely the driver or manufacturer has had some sort of security compromise or is malicious.

Comment: @user71659 will the name of driver cause this issue? It's a test driver written by me. It's not a official name, and I have [update the log with driver name](https://gist.github.com/7934345/9e9402f739b17f8773b80bc2f9e6c8b7#file-log-L151).

Comment: @user71659 if you need something else, just let me know. And THX!!!!!

Comment: So you wrote the driver yourself and sent it to Microsoft for WHQL testing and signing?

Comment: @user71659 Yes, [screen sortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktkR4.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the screenshot in the comments, your driver was submitted for WHQL test signing. The problem is likely that your system you are installing on is [not properly configured](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/whql-test-signature-program) for test signed drivers.

Comment: how can I make a reales one? [I followed these steps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/dashboard/hardware-certification-submissions). If its a test version, there is no other checkbox(options) when I saw on the site when I make a submission.

Comment: now on win 10 test machine, I installed the 'test version' driver for a new Test Report from HLK Studio, and with that report for a new Submission to see what going on.

Answer (score 0):

you may remove EV certificate from .sys and only add Microsoft certificate.
that's what WDK team suggested to me.